# Is the adjective "big" in Disney's new film The BFG redundant?

Tags: american-english

"The BFG" stands for "The Big Friendly Giant". But I'm curious, is the "big" part of the title considered redundant because "giant" already means big? Otherwise, I suppose there are small giants and big giants to begin with. I'd like to ask native English speakers specifically.

Comment: Yes, it's probably redundant. In fact, if you google "big friendly giant redundant", you get some relevant hits, including an academic paper: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://bridging.uvt.nl/pdf/krahmer_noordewier_goudbeek_koolen_cogsci_2013.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjSgLm49_vNAhVJLyYKHRaSBOIQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHRzSIVI94ghSlXLlCtxutV6-m71A

Comment: Could be humorously intentional.

Comment: similar to the phrase "big fat" as in 'My Big Fat Greek Wedding'

Comment: I always thought it was a play on "Big Fucking Gun.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai *the BFG* was a book long before a gun.

Comment: I think that you would say that it was "naively redundant" - implying that the person who **named** the giant had a naive grasp of English - eg was a child.

Answer (score 1):

It could be, but not necessarily.  I haven't seen the film, so I wouldn't know for sure.  However, it could refer to him being big for a giant.  Compared to the average giant, he's big.  It'd not be unlike saying the "*big* galaxy" or the "*big* colossus."  As adjectives, "galactic" and "colossal" mean big.  As nouns, though, they may be big compared to everything else, but compared to their own kind, they can be big or small or somewhere in between. If the film only contains one giant, then maybe it's redundant--that is unless he's even bigger than anyone would expect a giant to be.

Comment: To complicate things even more, the BFG is actually one of the smaller giants in the story.

Comment: Lol!  I didn't know that.  Maybe it's meant to be ironic then--like naming a big guy "Tiny" or a fat guy "Slim."

Answer (score 0):

It's not technically redundant, because "Giant" is his species/race. It'd be like saying "Big Friendly Human" or "Small Mean Elf".

But, it can also be taken as redundant, because it's not unusual for kids to apply extra descriptive terms. Nor would it be out of place for the befuddled BFG to talk about himself in such a manner.